# Allowing Remote Connection in IIS on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, remote-connection, iis-7.5

I'm trying to give access to a website in IIS on my Win 7 machine to another person on my network. He's unable to access it. I was wondering if perhaps it was because IIS isn't configured to allow remote connections (I seem to remember having to do this sort of thing on Win XP).

I've hunted around in IIS and googled but am not finding a way to configure remote connections on Win 7. Some of the answers I've found seem to refer to Win Server 2008 and talk about a management service in IIS Manager, but it doesn't appear to be present on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was Windows Firewall that was the culprit. I enabled domain access and now the website is visible to the other user.

Answer (score 20):

To enable http access through Windows Firewall on Windows 7

From the start menu begin typing "Allow a program through Windows Firewall".

Scroll the bottom of the list and look for World Wide Web Services (HTTP) and enable it on your networks.

Comment: after doing things chris marisic saied, you must open "windows firewall with advanced security" and find 3 rules started with "World Wide Web Services". then enable them