# Configure IIS in Windows 10 to allow access

Tags: networking, windows-10, iis

On my PC, I have IIS running.

First, I verified I could access the text file **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.txt** by browsing to http://localhost/test.txt.

Next, I substituted my IP address, and browsed to the same file: http://192.168.2.207/test.txt.

So, I passed this URL to a coworker, but it times out for him: http://192.168.2.207/test.txt

If I go in and turn off Windows Firewall, he can access the file just fine.

I cannot find the settings for IIS on Windows 10.

How do I configure IIS on Windows 10 to allow other PCs on the network to browse files and folders in my **wwwroot** folder?

Some seem to think this post answers my question:

[Allowing Remote Connection in IIS on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/254558/65442)

Not really. That question is about Windows 7. Windows 10 is a much different animal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing Remote Connection in IIS on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/254558/allowing-remote-connection-in-iis-on-windows-7)

Comment: I can probably make that solve my issue. Is there no way to get into the IIS settings on Windows 10 anymore?

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901434/iis-manager-in-windows-10

Comment: @Jatin - that is the post I used to see how to get IIS installed. Notice my comment on there dated before before this. After installing IIS on Windows 10, how do you get to it?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, that post is Windows 7. Mine says Windows 10. Should I edit my post to put Windows 10 in bold?

Comment: @jp2code Once the IIS is installed properly it is much easy to open IIS Manager... Windows Key + R --> inetmgr --> Enter  :)

Comment: @Jatin: I get **Windows cannot find 'inetmgr'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.**

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a firewall misconfiguration, nothing to do with IIS itself.  Win 10 isn't that different, and so far you've provided no info to show how the marked duplicate is not applicable to you (beyond a different Windows version).   When you followed the solutions on the marked duplicate (although it's marked a Win7) to allow HTTP through the Firewall (and ensure its set in the right FW profile) what happened?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: IIS is running. The firewall now allows HTTP, but I still don't see how to open the IIS Manager. `inetmgr` should work, but does not.

Comment: It looks like IIS did not install correctly. I removed it, added it back, now it works. No reboot required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows must have corrupted my IIS install.

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to pull up the **Run Command**.

Enter **OptionalFeatures.exe** to pull up Windows Features.

Uncheck the *Internet Information Services* box.

Click OK to save.

After Windows finished, do these steps again to bring up the Windows Features dialog.

This time, while checking *Internet Information Services*, I also check the *Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core* below it.

Click OK to save.

When Windows finishes, my IIS folder was in the **Windows Administrative Tools** folder (filed under **W** in Windows 10).

[image: screenshot]